# Laravel 5.4 + Dingo Api can't get array of post form-data

Tags: laravel, post, dingo-api

everybody. I building Laravel api application with DingoApi and I can't get data from postman with ***"form-data"*** format. 
I trying to retreive data with DingoApi functionality, and with Laravel's

```
Route::post('/test', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return request();
});

$api->post('test', function (Request $request){
    return response()->json($request->getContent());
});
```

And just can see something like this

`{"------WebKitFormBoundary5OJm609mWgC6xr8r\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name":"\"test1\"\r\n\r\nval1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary5OJm609mWgC6xr8r\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"test2\"\r\n\r\nval2\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary5OJm609mWgC6xr8r--\r\n"}`,

but with "raw" everything allright.

So, how I can get array from POST query?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$request->all()` to retrieve all data in the request as an array.

You might be interested in checking the Laravel doc for [Retrieving Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input)

Helping with a little screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

Lastly, most of the time, the best solution is in the doc of a tool, software, language, framework. Make it the first point of information.

Hope this helps :)